# R is a PID(principal integral domain), and $pR+aR=cR$ then how can we say $p \in cR$?

Tags: ring-theory, ideals, principal-ideal-domains

R is a PID(principal integral domain), and $pR+aR=cR$ then how can we say $p \in cR$?

I know that $pr_1+ar_2 = cr_3 \\ c | (pr_1+ar_2) $

then how can we prove that $c|p$

Comment: $p\in pR\subseteq pR+aR=cR$.

Comment: Thank you........

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown So in above expression, can i put $r_2 = 0 \implies c | pr_1$? I recently started ring theory. Pls explain.